# How to rotate axis labels when using a matplotlib histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot that looks like this, and I am trying to make the x axis labels more readable:

[image]

This is what I tried and the error I got:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `plt` from the call to `hist()`, which is not what you want. It is common to import matplotlib as `plt`, assuming that is what was intended here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [1, 2, 3, 4]

p = plt.hist(data)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')

plt.show()
```

[image]